# How to turn data structure taken from file to a function

Tags: function, file, haskell

This is my try of doing a DFA in Haskell. The DFA works, but now I want it to read some file instead of a hardcoded table. Was done using `foldl`. Now the problem is that I need the function `table` to be defined, and I want that the function `t` don't need to have defined `table`, just take it from memory. If I use 3 parameters in `t`, then I can't use `foldl`.

```
module DFA where

data DFA = DFA { intialState :: String
               , isAccepting :: String -> Bool
               , transition  :: String -> Char -> String
               }

-- estado inicial
i = "Q1"

-- criterio de aceptación
a = (`elem` ["Q1"])

table :: [((String, Char), String)]
table = [(("Q1",'A'), "Q2")
        ,(("Q1",'B'), "Q1")
        ,(("Q2",'A'), "Q1")
        ,(("Q2",'B'), "Q2")]

strToRow :: [String] -> [((String, Char), String)]
strToRow str = map crea_tupla por_espacios
  where
    crea_tupla [x,y,z] = ((x, head y), z)
    por_espacios = map words str

readDFA :: String -> IO ()
readDFA filename = do
                  contenidos <- readFile filename
                  print . strToRow . lines $ contenidos

t n c = case lookup (n,c) table of
          Just x -> x
          _      -> error "transición errónea"

dfa = DFA i a t

testDFA :: DFA -> [Char] -> Bool
testDFA (DFA i a t) = a . foldl t i
```

The file format is easy, only state char next:

```
Q1 A Q2
Q1 B Q1
Q2 A Q1
Q2 B Q2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foldl` even if you add a third argument. Suppose you define

```
t tab n c = case lookup (n,c) tab of
      Just x -> x
      _      -> error "transición errónea"
```

so that `t` acts on the new parameter `tab` instead of the fixed `table`. To use `foldl` you now need to use

```
dfa = DFA i a (t table)
```

This is because `t tab` is a two argument function, obtained from the three argument function `t` by fixing its first argument. For this to actually work, `table` must be what you have just read from the file. Perhaps you need something like (completely untested):

```
readDFA :: String -> IO ()
readDFA filename = do
              contenidos <- readFile filename
              let table = strToRow . lines $ contenidos
                  dfa = DFA i a (t table)
              print (testDFA dfa "some string")
```